# Solve the inequality $|\arccos(\cos(x))|<\pi/4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

To solve this exercise,

$$|\arccos(\cos(x))|<\pi/4$$

I have thought to apply this condition,
$$|f(x)|<k, \quad k\in \Bbb R^+, \iff -k<f(x)<k$$

Hence,

$$-\frac \pi4<\arccos(\cos(x))<\frac \pi4$$
Being $\arccos\colon [-1,1]\to [0,\pi]$, I can have

$$\cos\left(-\frac \pi4\right)<\cos(\arccos(\cos(x)))<\cos\left(\frac \pi4\right) \iff \frac{\sqrt2}2<\cos(x)<\frac{\sqrt2}2$$

false for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Are they correct my steps?

Comment: Recall that $\arccos$ is **not** the inverse function of $\cos$. Also it is easy to verify that $\frac{\pi}6$ is a solution. Finally $\arccos(\cos x)$ is a periodic and non negative function.

Comment: @dfnu Then I remember not correctly. $\arccos(\cos(x)) = x+2\Bbb Zπ$. And is it more easy? Then the solution is $-\frac \pi4<x<\frac \pi4$!

Comment: Certainly drawing a graph of $y=\arccos (\cos x)$ might be of help understanding the situation.

Comment: Note that there is **no value of $y$** for which $-\tfrac{\pi}{4}<\arccos y < 0$. So your inequality $-\tfrac{\pi}{4} < \arccos y< \tfrac{\pi}{4}$ reduces to $0\leq \arccos y<\tfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @MPW Yes of course: the $\text{im} f=[0,\pi]$ and $]-\pi/4,0[$ it is out from $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $\arccos:[-1,1] \to [0,\pi]$ is 1-1 and onto, so $|\arccos \cos x|<\tfrac{\pi}{4}$ is equivalent to $\arccos\cos x \in [0,\tfrac{\pi}{4})$.

Since $\arccos$ is strictly decreasing on its domain, this is equivalent to $\cos x \in (\cos\tfrac{\pi}{4},\cos 0] = (\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2},1]$.

This is true for $x\in(-\tfrac{\pi}{4} + 2\pi k,\tfrac{\pi}{4} + 2\pi k)$ for integers $k$.

Comment: I certainly wasn't lucid :-) If you see the comments I have written the answer $-\frac \pi4<x<\frac \pi4$ in $[0,2\pi[$. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes. But you are not restricted to $[0,2\pi)$, so you should account for all solutions.

Comment: I'm agree with you.I have written $\arccos(\cos(x)) = x+2\Bbb Zπ$ and to be more fast I have not put the periodicity.

Answer (score 1):

One of your steps is incorrect.  Taking the cosine of an inequality - in your case a double inequality - does not necessarily respect the direction of the inequality symbol because the cosine is not always nonincreasing or nondecreasing.  Indeed, between $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$ the cosine changes from increasing to decreasing.

If you wanted to salvage that step you could break it up into cases:

Case 1. $0\leq\cos(\arccos(\cos(x)))<\cos\left(\frac \pi4\right)$ where the cosine is nondecreasing and so taking the cosine does not change the direction of the inequalities

and

Case 2. $\cos\left(-\frac \pi4\right)<\cos(\arccos(\cos(x)))\leq0$ where the cosine is nonincreasing and so taking the cosine changes the direction of the inequalities.

Comment: Thank you very much....I'm not so sane these days. :-)